# Unable to get value of last <th> in a table/list

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-4

I am unable to get the value of the last item and update the next item accordingly not sure what I should do. I have tried `:last-child` too but that does not seem to return the desired values.

```
if ($("tbody").children().length == 0) {

            var item = `<tr>
                            <th scope="row">1</th>
                            <td>
                                <p>This is a paragraph</p>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" style="margin-right:1rem;">Complete</button>
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-light">Edit</button>
                            </td>
                        </tr>`

            $("tbody").append(item);
        } else {
            var lastValue = parseInt($("tbody th:last-of-type").html());
            item = `<tr><th scope="row">` + (lastValue + 1) + `</th>
                                                                <td>
                                                                    <p>This is a para</p>
                                                                </td>
                                                                <td>
                                                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" style="margin-right:1rem;">Complete</button>
                                                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-light">Edit</button>
                                                                </td></tr>`

            $("tbody").append(item);
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using `:last-of-type` I used `:last` instead which seems to return the correct values and I am able to update the number of row accordingly.

```
if ($("tbody").children().length == 0) {

                var item = `<tr>
                                <th scope="row">1</th>
                                <td>
                                    <p>This is a paragraph</p>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" style="margin-right:1rem;">Complete</button>
                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-light">Edit</button>
                                </td>
                            </tr>`

                $("tbody").append(item);
            } else {
                var lastValue = parseInt($("tbody th:last").html());
                item = `<tr><th scope="row">` + (lastValue + 1) + `</th>
                                                                    <td>
                                                                        <p>This is a para</p>
                                                                    </td>
                                                                    <td>
                                                                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" style="margin-right:1rem;">Complete</button>
                                                                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-light">Edit</button>
                                                                    </td></tr>`

                $("tbody").append(item);
            }
```